# Imported mesh to BABYLON.Mesh

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I have a problem to use CSG on imported meshes, here's my code:

var a;
    var b;

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "./public/Models/", "model1.stl", scene, function (newMeshes) {
    // Set the target of the camera to the first imported mesh
    camera.target = newMeshes[0];
    a = newMeshes[0];
});



BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "./public/Models/", "model2.stl", scene, function (newMeshes) {
    // Set the target of the camera to the first imported mesh
    //camera.target = newMeshes[0];
    b = newMeshes[0];
});


var aCSG = BABYLON.CSG.FromMesh(a);
var bCSG = BABYLON.CSG.FromMesh(b);
```

"var a" and "var b" are undefined and Debug told me that

"BABYLON.CSG: Wrong Mesh type, must be BABYLON.Mesh"

Is there any method to convert imported mesh to BABYLON.MESH?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is because the ImportMesh is async, you have to move your code in the callbacks section:

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "./public/Models/", "model1.stl", scene, function (newMeshes) {
    // Set the target of the camera to the first imported mesh
    camera.target = newMeshes[0];
    a = newMeshes[0];
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "./public/Models/", "model2.stl", scene, function (newMeshes) {
    // Set the target of the camera to the first imported mesh
    //camera.target = newMeshes[0];
    b = newMeshes[0];

var aCSG = BABYLON.CSG.FromMesh(a);
var bCSG = BABYLON.CSG.FromMesh(b);
});



});
```